# Simplifying a Decay Process with Centre of Mass Frame

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics

I am considering a process where a particle decays into a pair of particles, where the incoming particle has momentum $-p$ and the two outgoing particles have momenta $q$ and $r= -p - q$.

When analysing the matrix element squared for this process, I end up with expressions like $r^2 (q -p ) \cdot (p-r)$ which I am not sure how to simplify.

I assume that since we are free to choose a frame, we could choose the centre of mass frame, which implies that the incoming particle is at rest and that the two outgoing particles move away from each other in opposite directions, how does this help to simplify the expression above?  In that case, the incoming particle has zero $3$-momentum and the two outgoing particles have opposite $3$-momenta.

Comment: In the center of mass frame $p=0$ and $q=-r$

Comment: Won't the ingoing particle in the rest frame have momentum $p = (m,0,0,0)$?

Comment: In the particle’s own frame (it’s center of mass) it is not moving - the rest of the world is.

Comment: It's not moving, but doesn't it still have energy due to its rest mass, so the first component of the energy-momentum will be its mass?

Comment: Theres just a misunderstanding here because there is a bit of a lack of exactness here. You are right that the 4-momentum isn't zero, it is meant that $\vec{p}=0$ and that $\vec{q}=-\vec{r}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for clarifying.